# Can I create a counter that outputs the following counters

Tags: javascript, loops

I need a 2 counter, `i` & `j` that output the following counters for each iteratation:

```
0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,4
```

Counter variable sequence to achieve the above when output to console.log is as follows:

```
i,j,j,j,j,i,j,j,j,i,j,j,i,j
```

With each iteration, when i increments, j must start it's incrementation at i + 1 and must complete it's loop for each incrementation of i.

Each counter value will be used to present option from an array for comparison with one another.

I've tried using a nested for loop and it has not worked. I am also  calling a function containing the second loop with some success but want to know if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this.

```
function createValues() {
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var counter_i = i;
        decreasingLoop(counter_i);
    }
}
var k = 1; // counter for inner values loop
function decreasingLoop(get_i) {
    for (j = k; j < 10; j++) {
    // functions using the counters are entered here.
    if (j == 9) { // increments k so that the next time the counter runs it starts at +1 from previous iteration)
        k++;
        }
    }
    j = k;
}
```

I am getting the desired results but want to know if there is a simpler way to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Could you show your attempt using the nested `for` loops?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i< 4; i++){
  console.log(i)
  for(var j = i+1; j<= 4; j++){
    console.log(j)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write out your desired output in a different format, the solution may become a little clearer:

```
i: 0
  j: 1,2,3,4

i: 1
  j: 2,3,4

i: 2
  j: 3,4

i: 3
  j: 4
```

As you can see from the above example, `i` increases linearly, and only takes the values of `0` through to `3`. Each time `i` takes a new value, `j` loops from `i+1` up to 4. Using this idea, you can create an outer for loop for `i` (which loops from 0 to 3) and an inner for loop for `j` which starts at `i+1` and finished when `j` is equal to 4:

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  for(let j = i+1; j <= 4; j++) {
    console.log(j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following nested loop - notice that in second loop initial for value is `j=i+1`

```js
let n=4, m=5;

for(let i=0; i<n; i++) for(let j=i+1; j<m; j++) {
  console.log({i,j});
}
```

Comment: This may work but as an answer its still incomplete